# how to get product list - updated with the correct code

Tags: javascript

help on how to get the product listings from the HTML using JavaScript.

based on the HTML the class names are random generated so there is no way to get it directly.

only get the list of product inside the  tag.

objective is to get the product name and price.

thank in advance.

```
<div class="root">
    <div><a href="test.html">test</a></div>
    <div class="SlZgBjnLiz">
        <div class="_2hqU7qTypZ">
            <div class="dLZJAZVTAg">
                <main class="_3egzkmmXgV">
                    <div class="_2RJeLsMmpi">
                        <div class="dkyUCQEdrH  _21mUCnWSZd">
                            <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                                    <a href="1.html">
                                        <p class="_1gJzwc_bJS _2rwkILN6KA mT74Grr7MA nCFolhPlNA lqg5eVwdBz uxIDPd3H13 _30RANjWDIv">Iphone 11 Pro Max and Iphone 11 pro and Iphone 11</p>
                                        <p class="_1gJzwc_bJS _2rwkILN6KA mT74Grr7MA nCFolhPlNA lqg5eVwdBz _19l6iUes6V _3k5LISAlf6">PHP 41,000</p>
                                        <p class="_1gJzwc_bJS _2rwkILN6KA mT74Grr7MA nCFolhPlNA lqg5eVwdBz _19l6iUes6V _30RANjWDIv">some descriptiont</p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                                    <a href="2.html">
                                        <p class="_1gJzwc_bJS _2rwkILN6KA mT74Grr7MA nCFolhPlNA lqg5eVwdBz uxIDPd3H13 _30RANjWDIv">Iphone X</p>
                                        <p class="_1gJzwc_bJS _2rwkILN6KA mT74Grr7MA nCFolhPlNA lqg5eVwdBz _19l6iUes6V _3k5LISAlf6">PHP 41,000</p>
                                        <p class="_1gJzwc_bJS _2rwkILN6KA mT74Grr7MA nCFolhPlNA lqg5eVwdBz _19l6iUes6V _30RANjWDIv">some descriptiont</p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                                    <a href="3.html">
                                        <p class="_1gJzwc_bJS _2rwkILN6KA mT74Grr7MA nCFolhPlNA lqg5eVwdBz uxIDPd3H13 _30RANjWDIv">Iphone 4</p>
                                        <p class="_1gJzwc_bJS _2rwkILN6KA mT74Grr7MA nCFolhPlNA lqg5eVwdBz _19l6iUes6V _3k5LISAlf6">PHP 41,000</p>
                                        <p class="_1gJzwc_bJS _2rwkILN6KA mT74Grr7MA nCFolhPlNA lqg5eVwdBz _19l6iUes6V _30RANjWDIv">some descriptiont</p>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('main').forEach(main => {
        main.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(product => {
            const product_details = product.querySelectorAll('p');
            const productName = product.textContent;
            const productHref = product.getAttribute('href');
            console.log(product_details[0].textContent + " - "+ product_details[1].textContent);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provide the code you tried so far

Comment: sorry but i don't know much about front-end so basically my boss just ask me to do scrap a page which is like this. i only know how to scrap a page with a defined class name but unlike this one.

Comment: let me see if i can help ;)

Comment: What is not clear to me is what you need about the product, where is stored the code you need to colect?

Comment: basically what i need is to get the product name. then once i get the product name i need to open the link and get other information inside the page that the product description and quantity.

Comment: `<div="root">` is invalid HTML.

Comment: @connexo sorry forgot to type class will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the name of the product you can just get all the  elements and then access their text value.
The code would be something like:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('main').forEach(main => {
    main.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(product => {
        const productName = product.textContent;
        const productHref = product.getAttribute('href');
        console.log(productName + " " + productHref);
        //Do what you need.
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="root">
  <div class="SlZgBjnLiz">
    <div class="_2hqU7qTypZ">
      <div class="dLZJAZVTAg">
        <main class="_3egzkmmXgV">
          <div class="_2RJeLsMmpi">
            <div class="dkyUCQEdrH  _21mUCnWSZd">
              <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                  <a href="">product 1</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                  <a href="">product 2</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                  <a href="">product 3</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                  <a href="">product 4</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                  <a href="">product 5</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                  <a href="">product 6</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                  <a href="">product 7</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="An6bc8d5sQ _9IlksbU0Mo _2t71A7rHgH">
                <div class="TpQXuJG_eo">
                  <a href="">product 8</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Browsers that support arrow functions also support `forEach` on `NodeList` and also `let`  and `const`. Make sure not to use `getElementsByTagName` and instead do `querySelectorAll('a')`.

Comment: I tried my code with Google Chrome and worked just fine, but when I modify it with your suggestion it keeps giving me errors like "forEach is not a function" and "querySelectorAll" is not defined. But *let* and *const* are better than *var* I guess.

Comment: I have added the improved version. Tell what your Chrome says.

Comment: works like a charm. now is there a way for me to get the value of the href and open it in another browser for me the get other information of the said product? but seriously this code work and thank you very much.

Comment: btw another thing is what if there is another div above with <a href=""> and don't like it to be listed. like i put the <a href=""> above the <main> and i only want to get all the links inside the main?

Comment: @vher edited the answer to get also the *href* attribute. Hope it's what you wanted.

Comment: @connexo it doesn't work, but it doesn't give me any error. I guess there's just something wrong with my Chrome ahah

Comment: `<div="root">` is invalid HTML.

Comment: @connexo both actually work with me using google chrome.

Comment: @vher choose the improved version then.

Comment: @RiccardoChimisso your code work thank you bro. just 1 more thing i tried to add 1 div above <main> with <a href=""> from your code it is also listed. is there's a way for me to only get the products which is inside <main>

Comment: @RiccardoChimisso i use the improved version since queryselectorall is more practical from puppeteer.

Comment: @vher does the class of the main element also changes?

Comment: @RiccardoChimisso yes. in all honesty im trying to scrap data from carousell.ph and trying to get products from search https://www.carousell.ph/search/iphone?

Comment: @RiccardoChimisso i tried doing this const products = document.querySelectorall('main').getElementsByTagName('a'); but it give me error "Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorall is not a function"

Comment: @vher edited the answer with your new request. Look whether it works or not. I didn't modify the "improved version" but I changed the first version.

Comment: @vher edited the answer again, check it out. It should work better.

Comment: *document.querySelectorall is not a function* document.querySelector**A**ll is.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the data(product 1 to product 8) placed inside of the anchor tags then you can just try the code below:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
     console.log(elements[i].text);
     //  elements[i].text will give you products list.
     //  put your logic to use the values 
}
```

Hope this helps.